# Windows hosting solutions (VPS and dedicated)

Tags: windows, hosting, vps

I am confused over hosting solutions for windows.

I am looking for VPS as well dedicated which is reliable and great customer service.

I am feeling there are very few options available for windows hosting as compare to linux.

I need suggestion for hosting from SO community.

Comment: It's probably a price thing: if you want a Windows VPS you'll have to pay or rent a Windows server licence. You can pay monthly with your hosting, but it's won't be trivial compared to the cost of the hosting.

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a think about cloud hosting. Since this may come with virtual service support and expandability would be better than the VPS